# apiKey as query param in Swagger UI 2.0

Tags: java, rest, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-maven-plugin

**Context** : Converting Swagger from current REST documentation in 1.2 spec to 2.0

**Environment** : Java 8, swagger-maven-plugin 3.0.1, swagger annotations (com.wordnik)

**Where I am stuck**: I was able to generate the REST API documentation successfully. However, REST APIs need an ApiKey as Query param. In 1.2 spec, this was added using the following snippet in index.html

```
function addApiKeyAuthorization() {
    var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
    log("key: " + key);
    if(key && key.trim() != "") {
        log("added key " + key);
        //window.authorizations.add("api_key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "query"));
        window.authorizations.add("apiKey", new ApiKeyAuthorization("apiKey", key, "header"));
    }
  }

  $('#input_apiKey').change(function() {
    addApiKeyAuthorization();
  });

  // if you have an apiKey you would like to pre-populate on the page for demonstration purposes...

    var apiKey = "ABCD";
    $('#input_apiKey').val(apiKey);
    addApiKeyAuthorization();
```

However, for 2.0 spec, my search led to the following changes in the yaml file.

```
securityDefinitions:
 UserSecurity:
  type: apiKey
  in: header
  name:myApiKey
```

The current index.html has the following in window function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "http://someCoolsite.com/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
  window.ui = ui
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further exploration, I have found answer to my question above.

First : My index.html is as below:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  window.onload = function() {
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "http://www.webhostingsite.com/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
  window.ui = ui
}
window.onFailure = function(data) {
    log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
}

function addApiKeyAuthorization() {
  var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
  log("key: " + key);
  if(key && key.trim() != "") {
    log("added key " + key);
    //window.authorizations.add("api_key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "query"));
    window.authorizations.add("apiKey", new ApiKeyAuthorization("apiKey", key, "query"));
  }
}

$('#input_apiKey').change(function() {
  addApiKeyAuthorization();
});
});
```

Then, I updated my swagger.json to be as below:

```
   {
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "apiKey": {
     "type": "apiKey",
     "name": "apiKey",
      "in": "query"
    }
  },
  "host" : "<api base path>",
  "basePath" : "/v1",
  "security": [{"apiKey": []}]", //Global security (applies to all operations)
  .......
```

Third: Hosted index.html and swagger.json on AWS S3 for static web hosting.

The part where I went wrong was, `"security": [{"apiKey": []}]"`.

I was doing `"security":{"apiKey":[]}` all the while forgetting that value of "security" is a list.

Hope this helps.